# Silverlight: Define a custom ControlTemplate in C# instead of XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I believe I'm using Silverlight 3.0... I just downloaded it this week.  Assuming the charting namespace references the [System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization assembly in the Silverlight Toolkit](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/28/silverlight-toolkit-released-with-charting-databinding.aspx), please help me create the DataPointStyle using C#, as it's expressed in XAML below:

```
<charting:Chart
    Title="Simple Column Annotations - Bottom">
    <charting:ColumnSeries
        DependentValuePath="Value"
        IndependentValuePath="Key"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <!-- HERE IS WHAT I WANT TO CREATE IN C#: -->
        <charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle
                                    Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Stroke="Black"/>
                                <Grid
                                    Background="#aaffffff"
                                    Margin="0 -20 0 0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <TextBlock
                                        Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"
                                        FontWeight="Bold"
                                        Margin="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
        <!-- END -->
    </charting:ColumnSeries>
</charting:Chart>
```

My goal is to build a library of easy-to-use templates that can be applied to series in a chart.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define control templates in C# alone.  I'm not sure why you would want to?

Just add the XAML for your set of control templates as resources in your library.  Use the `XamlReader` to load these templates into objects which you can then expose publicly.

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks. I'll put the XAML into a resource dictionary.